# bash / sh -c not working with multiple pipes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So, the commands:

```
dmesg | grep 'Attached SCSI disk' | awk '{ print $5}'
```

when executed directly from shell, works like it should, outputting:

> `[sdb]`
>   `[sdc]`
>   `[sda]`

But, when I'm launching it with:

```
sh -c "dmesg | grep 'Attached SCSI disk' | awk '{ print $5}'"
# or
bash -c "dmesg | grep 'Attached SCSI disk' | awk '{ print $5}'"
```

I get:

> `[    2.460353] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk`
>   `[    2.461348] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk`
>   `[    2.464181] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk`

That clearly shows that the last pipe has not executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside, the antipattern `grep x | awk '{ stuff }'` can usually be simplified to just `awk '/x/{ stuff }'`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `$5` is getting evaluated too early.  Change it to `\$5`.

If you were to replace `bash` with `echo`, you would see that `$5` is being replace by the empty string:

```
 % echo "dmesg | grep 'Attached SCSI disk' | awk '{ print $5}'"
 dmesg | grep 'Attached SCSI disk' | awk '{ print }'
```

So, when bash evaluates the command, awk is going to print the entire line, not the fifth field.

When you escape the dollar sign (by pre-prending with a backslash), the variable `$5` is preserved:

```
% echo "dmesg | grep 'Attached SCSI disk' | awk '{ print \$5}'"
dmesg | grep 'Attached SCSI disk' | awk '{ print $5}'
```

Comment: Okay, that fixed it, is there any explanation why so?

Comment: The entire string is subject to parameter expansion prior to being passed to `sh` or `bash`. Because it is in double quotes, the `$5` is interpreted as a shell positional parameter. (The single quotes do not protect it; they are just characters in the string as well.)

Comment: As an aside you can simplify it to: `dmesg | awk '/Attached SCSI disk/ {print $5}'`

Answer (score 1):

There is a conflict between the shell and awk in their use and interpretation of `$1`, `$2`, ...

In all Bourne descendants (ash, bash, dash, ksh93, zsh), these indicate the numbered arguments as passed on the command line, while `$0` is replaced with the name of the currently running script or the name of the interactive shell.

In `awk`, `$1`, `$2`, ... refer to the corresponding *field* of the current *record*, i.e. the first, second, etc., word of the current input line.  `$0` always refers to the whole record, including any Field Separators.

When calling `awk` from a shell (script) you must make sure that the awk script is properly quoted.  To prevent shell interpolation, enclose the awk code inside single quotes.